# DownloadManager.Request Set absolute path Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm using DownloadManager.Request to download files (.mp3) and I cannot set an absolute path. 
I tried using the following methods: setDestinationInExternalFilesDir() and setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(). I havn't tried setDestinationUri() because I don't understand exactly how to use it.

Comment: Where exactly does this absolute path point to?

Comment: @CommonsWare the path is variable. It can be any path on the filesystem.

Comment: No, because neither you nor the process that `DownloadManager` coordinates with has write access to "any path on the filesystem". You need to provide a location that both you and `DownloadManager` can support.